# How to setup the connection to MongoDB's Docker container in GCP

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, google-cloud-platform, pymongo

I need help with setting up the connection between two VMs in GCP.

I have set up the first VM in Google Compute Engine, it uses the Container Optimized operating system (cos-stable-93-16623-39-21) with Docker installed, running the MongoDB image (mongo:5.0.4
). I want to create another VM with Docker and Python Script on the GCP and connect to the Mongo database from it using Python and Mongo's Python driver.

How can I achieve it? For the Python driver, I need some URL of the Mongo database, but how can I get the URL I need and will it be blocked by Docker?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You will need to expose the port(s) within the mongo deployment, then you will use the IP address of the host, where the mongodb is running to connect to it from the second VM (alternatively you can also use fqdn). Then you need to make sure the Firewall allows such communication.

Update with a quick example:

mongo vm:

```
user@instance-mongo ~ $ docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -p 27017:27017 -d mongo

user@instance-mongo ~ $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                                           NAMES
ae19ede390eb   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 seconds ago        Up 2 seconds                0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   frosty_bardeen
```

python instance:

```
user@instance-python ~ $ docker run -it --rm python:3-alpine sh
/ #
/ # pip install ipython pymongo
...<omitted for brevity>
/ # ipython
Python 3.10.0 (default, Nov 13 2021, 03:23:03) [GCC 10.3.1 20210424]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.30.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient
In [2]: client = MongoClient('mongodb://instance-mongo:27017')
In [3]: client.admin.command('ping')
Out[3]: {'ok': 1.0}
```

as you can see I've exposed port 27017 in mongo deployment, then from python instance connected to the `instance-mongo` (hostname of the vm) and sent a mongo `ping` command.

## example 2:

mongo vm:

```
user@instance-mongo ~ $ docker run -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=initdb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
c541d683279802b2fd90f7e8ca1a8f5f74562b31170f0c80977a60387b74a595
```

python vm:

```
<installed pymongo, ipython>
/ # ipython

# createing a client and pinging the db
In [1]: client = MongoClient('mongodb://root:example@instance-mongo:27017')
In [2]: client.initdb.command('ping')
Out[2]: {'ok': 1.0}

# db instance and checking for the list of collections
In [3]: db = client["initdb"]
In [4]: db.list_collection_names()
Out[4]: []

# collection instance and document instance
In [5]: collection = db['example_collection']
In [6]: document = {"name": "Corgam", "source": "stackoverflow", "question": 70157757}

# inserting the document and listing collections again
In [7]: collection.insert_one(document)
In [8]: db.list_collection_names()
Out[8]: ['example_collection']
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a tutorial for such communication between two VMs in GCP? Also maybe some tutorial for exposing ports in Mongo?

Comment: Let me look something up, I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: @Corgam, I've updated the answer with a quick example of how you can expose the mongo port and then connect to mongo from another instance

Comment: @Corgam added another example, just in case :)

Comment: Thank you for the examples, but I'm still trying to understand how to set it up on the GCP  EDIT:  So for example how to I connect to the Mongo from another VM

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand how to set up? You already have VMs, right?

Comment: Yes. I have a VM with Docker and Mongo, and another VM with Docker and Python script. I need to connect from that Python script to the Mongo. How do I get the IP of the Mongo database?

Comment: If you are running these VMs alongside each other, you can use the name of the vm instead of the IP, just like I did in the example.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, and what exactly did you mean with "Then you need to make sure the Firewall allows such communication."?

Comment: Cloud Firewall (under VPC Network - Firewall) has rules that describe what ingress and egress communications are possible within VPC. You want to make sure that there is a rule which does that. If you are using the default VPC and didn't delete any default rules, there should be one that already allows internal communications (as in between VMs in the same VPC), called default-allow-internal.

Comment: You are right, thanks!